# Add field to Omniauth user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I'm using omniauth with the identity strategy in my RoR 4 web app.

Following Ryan's RailsCast [304](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast) and [241](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast) The user model has been generated in the following way:

```
$ rails g model user provider:string uid:string name:string
```

And in my User model I have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :packages
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :links
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

Now, everythings work like a charm, but what about adding a new custom field to the user model?

Here's what I did:

1- Added the new filed to the user model and migrated:

```
t.string :stripe_customer_id
```

2- Added a custom field to my form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :stripe_customer_id %>
```

3- In my controller for the moment I permit all parameters (not very safe):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit!
end
```

4- Here's my problem: How to get this value inside my User model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :packages
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :links
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.stripe_customer_id = ?????????????
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

the metod self.from_omniauth(auth) in User controller is called by the session controller. In the session controller I have all the params I need.

Modified User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :packages
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :links
  def self.from_omniauth(auth,stripe_customer_id)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth,stripe_customer_id)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth,stripe_customer_id)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.stripe_customer_id = stripe_customer_id
    end
  end
end
```

and the new SessionController:

```
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"], params["stripe_customer_id"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to profiles_url
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data only that is provided by the Omniauth Providers. Here is a list where is has been referenced : https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema

Here is how you add the permit on the Devise :

In application_controller.rb

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:avatar, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

You can also create your own controller by doing something like this :

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

And then use that controller instead of the default with:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Comment: This didn't give me much help. Thank you anyway for your time.